# How to access a shared project data object from a method in iOS AppDelegate.cs?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

I'm trying to pass some data values from my shared project for access via an iOS AppDelegate.cs method. I don't want to go into too much detail here, as I don't want to limit the reach of this question. But the Method could be called at any point and is used to gain state information about the app, e.g. isLoggedIn etc.

We're using `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc` and have a CustomViewModelbase, but that probably not too relevant.

The values are mostly part of our `CustomViewModelbase`, I thought I could create some kind of global object on App.Xaml.cs, which would be accessibily in AppDelegate.cs

Here's what I have...

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc;
using ourapp.DTO;
using ourapp.Interfaces;
using ourapp.ViewModels;

namespace ourapp.Helpers
{
    public class UITestingHelper : CustomViewModelBase, IUITestingHelper
    {
        [PreferredConstructor]
        public UITestingHelper(
            ICustomNavigationService navigationService,
            IApiClient apiClient,
            IDependencyService dependencyService)
            : base(
                  navigationService,
                  apiClient,
                  dependencyService)
        {

        }
```

//

```
        UITestingBackdoor _status;
        public UITestingBackdoor Status
        {
            get
            {
                //var vm = (CustomViewModelBase)App.ViewModelLocator.Resolve(
                //      typeof(CustomViewModelBase));

                _status = new UITestingBackdoor()
                {
                    WillShowAccountPopup = base.HasMoreThanOneAccount,
                    AppUpdateAvailable = base.AppUpdateAvailable,
                    IsLoggedIn = App.IsLoggedIn,
                    IsConnected = App.Connectivity.IsConnected,
                };

                return _status;
            }
        }

        public string GetAppStatus()
        {
            string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert
                .SerializeObject(Status);

            return json;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my AppDelegate.cs method...

```
        [Export("UITestBackDoor:")]
        public NSString UITestBackDoor(NSString value)
        {
            var status = App.UITestingStatus.GetAppStatus();

            return (NSString)status;
        }
```

However, the object is basically a view model in it's own rights and has dependancy injection to initialise it. However, it isn't registered against a specific view and therefore can not be resolved.

My exact issue is that although a property on my CustomViewModelbase is getting it's value set. When the values is accessed in my global object, the value is empty.

I believe this is related to dependancy injection. However, I'm starting to think there must be a simpler solution?

Yes, I will want to do this for Android as well, but first things first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a global variable in App.cs , initialize it in constructor.

Return the value from a public method  and access it in iOS project .

#### Forms App.cs

```
    UITestingHelper helper;
    public string GetAppStatus()
    {
        return helper.UITestingStatus.GetAppStatus;
    }
```

#### iOS AppDelegate.cs

```
  public NSString UITestBackDoor(NSString value)
        {
            return (App.Current as App).GetAppStatus();
        }
```